# NUnitLite and Selenium Unattended Test Issue

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have a console application that uses NUnitLite and runs a single selenium test in a headless browser. If I play the application from visual studio, it runs perfectly. What I want is to compile the application into an .exe and run it from a task scheduler. The problem is that when I compile it, the .exe just flashes the command prompt and does nothing. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I've also tried running with NUnitConsole by installing "NUnit.Console-3.15.0.msi" and by running the following command

> nunit3-console
> "C:\Deployments\PSA_AutoImport_Runner\AutoImport_Runner.dll"

NUnitConsole returns the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException: Remote test
> agent exited with non-zero exit code 1    at
> NUnit.Engine.Services.TestAgency.OnAgentExit(Process process, Guid
> agentId)    at
> NUnit.Engine.Services.TestAgency.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.b__0(Object
> sender, EventArgs e)    at System.Diagnostics.Process.OnExited()    at
> System.Diagnostics.Process.RaiseOnExited()    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    at
> System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(Object
> state, Boolean timedOut)
>
> Errors, Failures and Warnings
>
> 1. Error : NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException : Unable to acquire
>    remote process agent
>    --NUnitEngineException Unable to acquire remote process agent    at NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.CreateAgentAndRunnerIfNeeded()
>    at NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.RunTests(ITestEventListener
>    listener, TestFilter filter)

Any help/direction towards the NUnitLite way or the NUnitConsole way would be much appreciated. If you need more info, just let me know.

NugetPackages:

[image: NugetPackages]

Program Code:

```
using NUnit.Common;
using NUnitLite;
using System.Reflection;


return new AutoRun(typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
                .Execute(args, new ExtendedTextWrapper(Console.Out), Console.In);
```

Test Code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using ***.Application.Services;
using ***.AutoImport_Runner;
using ***.Api.Service.Models;

namespace NUnitSeleniumTest
{
    public class Tests
    {
        
        private TestServer _server;

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            // Arrange
            IWebHostBuilder builder = new WebHostBuilder()
               .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .Build()
                ).UseStartup<Startup>();

            _server = new TestServer(builder);
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            _server = null;
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task Test1()
        {           
            var filePath = @"C:\***Downloads";

            //Browser needs to be headless
            var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");

            //Download the file
            using (var webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions))
            {
                var enableDownloadCommandParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "behavior", "allow" },
                    { "downloadPath", filePath }
                };
                var result = ((ChromeDriver)webDriver).ExecuteCdpCommand("Page.setDownloadBehavior", enableDownloadCommandParameters);

                webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("*********************");

                //Don't understand why this is needed but it breaks without it.
                webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

                //Also need this wait. Without it and the above wait, the code breaks.
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60));
                var element = wait.Until(condition =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Subfunction DDL
                        webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("SubFunctionCombobox")).Click();
                        webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("SubFunctionCombobox_283")).Click();
                        webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("SubFunctionCombobox_284")).Click();
                        webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("SubFunctionCombobox_286")).Click();
                        webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("SubFunctionCombobox_305")).Click();
                        webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("SubFunctionCombobox_306")).Click();

                        webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("_htmCanvasShield")).Click();

                        //StartDate EndDate
                        var dtNow = DateTime.Now.Date;
                        var dtEnd = dtNow.AddMonths(4).Date;

                        string dtNowStr = dtNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                        string dtEndStr = dtEnd.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

                        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript($"$('#StartDateCalendar').val('{dtNowStr}').change();");
                        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript($"$('#EndDateCalendar').val('{dtEndStr}').change();");


                        return true;
                    }
                    catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchElementException)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                //Export
                webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("RunButton")).Click();

                //Wait on the file to download Currently 500 seconds
                for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
                {
                    var fCount = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;
                    if (fCount > 0)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(10000); //Waiting here is necessary. Don't remember why.

                        //Get the file and remove the .crdownload from the path
                        var fileUrl = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).First();
                        if (fileUrl != null)
                        {
                            if (fileUrl.EndsWith(".crdownload")) fileUrl = fileUrl.Replace(".crdownload", "");
                            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileUrl))
                            {
                                var file = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, null, Path.GetFileName(stream.Name))
                                {
                                    Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
                                    ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                                };

                                //Post the file to ImportExportService
                                await PostAttachment(file);
                            }

                            //Delete the file from the folder
                            File.Delete(fileUrl);
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task PostAttachment(FormFile uploadFile)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadFile?.FileName?.Trim());
            FileStreamModel inputFileStreamModel = new()
            {
                DataStream = uploadFile?.OpenReadStream(),
                Length = uploadFile?.OpenReadStream()?.Length,
                ContentType = uploadFile?.ContentType,
                LastModified = DateTime.Now
            };
            inputFileStreamModel.SetFileNameAndType(fileName);


            var _importExportService = _server.Services.GetService<IImportExportService>();

            await _importExportService.ImportPSASpreadsheet(inputFileStreamModel, 9, null, null, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup Code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using ***.Application.Services;
using ***.Dal;
using ***.Dal.Repos;
using ***.Api.Result;

namespace ***.AutoImport_Runner
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _env = env;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IResultDto, ResultDto>();

            services.AddDbContext<***Context>((serviceProvider, options) =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer("************", sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                {
                    sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                    maxRetryCount: 2,
                    maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                    errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                });
            });

            services.AddTransient<IResultDto, ResultDto>();
            services.AddTransient<IImportExportService, ImportExportService>();
            services.AddTransient<IImportExportRepo, ImportExportRepo>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment _)
        {
           
        }

    }
}
```

ANSWER:

So, I ended up uninstalling the NUnit Console app that was installed by the .msi. I downloaded the NUnit.Console-3.15.0.zip and everything worked as it should.

Comment: I don't see a Main() in your code.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements

Comment: May we assume that 3.15.0.zip made your console run work correctly, but had no effect on the nunitlite run?

Comment: Either way, there's an apparent bug in the nunit-console msi as well as in nunitlite, if it doesn't work with an implicit entry point. 'Twould be nice to report them. :-)

Comment: Yes, 3.15.0.zip along with the correct ChromeDriver made the NUnitConole route work. Once that worked, I gave up on the NUnitLite way.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with posting an answer to your own question, and accepting it.